# Using multiple Leaves in Lucene Classifiers

Tags: java, lucene, document-classification

I am trying to use the KNearestNeighbour classifier in lucene. The document classifier accepts a leafReader in its constructor, for training the classifier.
The problem is that, the Index I am using to train the classifier has multiple leaves. But the constructor for the class only accepts one leaf, and I could not find a process to add the remaining LeafReaders to the Class. I might be missing out on something. Could anyone help please me out with this?

Here is the code I am using currently :

```
    FSDirectory index = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexLoc));
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
    LeafReaderContext leaf = leaves.get(0);
    LeafReader atomicReader = leaf.reader();
    KNearestNeighborDocumentClassifier knn = new KNearestNeighborDocumentClassifier(atomicReader, BM25, null, 10, 0, 0, "Topics", field2analyzer, "Text");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaves represent each segment of you index. In terms of performance and resource usage, you should iterate over the leaves, run the classification for each segment and accumulate your results.

```
for (LeafReaderContext context : indexReader.getContext().leaves()) {
  LeafReader reader = context.reader();
  // run for each leaf
}
```

If that is not possible, you can use the `SlowCompositeReaderWrapper` which, as the name suggests, might be very slow as it aggregates all the leaves on the fly.

```
LeafReader singleLeaf = SlowCompositeReaderWrapper.wrap(indexReader);
// run classifier on singleLeaf
```

Depending on your Lucene version, this sits in lucene-core or lucene-misc (since Lucene 6.0, I think). Also, this class is deprecated and scheduled for removal in Lucene 7.0.

The third option might be to run `forceMerge(1)` until you only have one segment and you can use the single leaf for this. However, forcing a merge down to a single segment has other issues and might not work for your use case. If you data is write-once and then only used for reading, you could use a forceMerge. If you have regular updates, you'll have to end up using the first option and aggregate the classification result yourself.

Comment: I am using lucene 6.3.
The first one is not an option for me, since I have to train the classifier all at once, aggregation will not be possible.
"SlowCompositeReaderWrapper" seems like a viable option for now. Thanks.